# NavigationView or using NavigationLink messes up while trying to Draw

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the below code which allows user to tap on the screen 4 times and each time it creates a point and draws a line between them. This work great when its a content view. But when I wrap it with `NavigationView` or if I create a different view and call it via `NavigationLink`, it messes up. It always puts the points on (0,0) coordinates. Where I click does not matter. I did some research and it seems NavigationView and NavigationLink really messes up the views. I saw a solution(which is comment out sections in the code) which includes adding `.coordinateSpace(name: "ZStack")` but it also does not work.

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct TappableRectangle: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var points: [CGPoint]
}
 
struct IdentifiablePoint: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let point: CGPoint
}
 
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var rectangles: [TappableRectangle] = []
    @State private var currentPoints: [IdentifiablePoint] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        //NavigationView { // Comment out if you want to try
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(0.75)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .gesture(
                    TapGesture()
                        .onEnded {
                            if currentPoints.count < 4 {
                                let tapLocation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view.convert(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view?.gestureRecognizers?.first?.location(in: UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view) ?? .zero, to: nil) ?? .zero
                                currentPoints.append(IdentifiablePoint(point: tapLocation))
                            }
                            
                            if currentPoints.count == 4 {
                                rectangles.append(TappableRectangle(points: currentPoints.map { $0.point }))
                                currentPoints.removeAll()
                            }
                        }
                )
            
            ForEach(rectangles) { rectangle in
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: rectangle.points[0])
                    path.addLine(to: rectangle.points[1])
                    path.addLine(to: rectangle.points[2])
                    path.addLine(to: rectangle.points[3])
                    path.closeSubpath()
                }
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
            }
            
            if currentPoints.count > 1 {
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: currentPoints[0].point)
                    for i in 1..<currentPoints.count {
                        path.addLine(to: currentPoints[i].point)
                    }
                    if currentPoints.count == 4 {
                        path.closeSubpath()
                    }
                }
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
            }
            
            ForEach(currentPoints) { point in
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color("HeliosensOrange"))
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    .position(point.point)
            }
        }
    //}.coordinateSpace(name: "ZStack") // Comment out if you want to try
    }
}
 
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose its a problem due to the deprecated `UIApplication.shared.windows.first`.
If you use the new `.onTapGesture` version which passes the tap location, everything works fine:

```
.onTapGesture { tapLocation in // HERE
    if currentPoints.count < 4 {
        currentPoints.append(IdentifiablePoint(point: tapLocation))
    }
                        
    if currentPoints.count == 4 {
        rectangles.append(TappableRectangle(points: currentPoints.map { $0.point }))
        currentPoints.removeAll()
    }
}
```